# How should I insert into my table composed of a composite key with JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I'm a beginner in JPA-Hibernate stuff and I wanted to know how should I update my join table declared in my PostgreSQL database.

There is a look on my tables :

**Shelters Table**

[image]

**Images Table**

[image]

**SheltersXImages Table**

[image]

I would like to update my table SheltersXImages which have a unique composite key composed of 2 foreign keys : "str_id" from the Shelters Table and "img_id" from the Images Table.

Should I :

- Create an entity to represent SheltersXImages Table and create a repository to insert into the table SheltersXImages manually ?
- Find a better idea ? I found some subjects about @IdClass @EmbeddedId or @JoinTable annotations but as I said I'm a beginner and I don't really understand if I could use them to solve my problem and which solution is the most appropriate.

There is a look on my entities at the moment :

**Shelter Entity**

```
open class SheltersStrEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "shelters_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="shelters_generator", sequenceName = "v1.shelters_str_str_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "str_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
open var strId: Long? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_siren", nullable = false)
open var strSiren: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_nic", nullable = false)
open var strNic: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_name", nullable = false)
open var strName: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_email", nullable = false)
open var strEmail: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_address", nullable = false)
open var strAddress: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_zip_code", nullable = false)
open var strZipCode: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_city", nullable = false)
open var strCity: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_phone", nullable = false)
open var strPhone: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_active", nullable = false)
open var strActive: Boolean? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_creation_datetime", nullable = false)
open var strCreationDatetime: OffsetDateTime? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "str_edit_datetime", nullable = false)
open var strEditDatetime: OffsetDateTime? = null

//Equals and hashcode ...
}
```

**Image Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images_img", schema = "v1", catalog = "hachiko")
open class ImagesImgEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "images_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="images_generator", sequenceName = "v1.images_img_img_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "img_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
open var imgId: Long? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "img_name", nullable = false)
open var imgName: String? = null
@Basic
@Column(name = "img_content", nullable = false)
open var imgContent: ByteArray? = null

//Equals and hashcode ...
}
```

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: Is it a many-to-many or a one-to-many relationship between Shelter and Image?

Comment: A OneToMany (A shelter can have many images)

Comment: But why do you need then the SheltersXImages table?

Comment: The relationship can be represented without using the relationship table and it is more performing as it will generate less sqls to insert and retrieve the data back.